# info window custom close button

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an instance of google.maps.InfoWindow, and it has a custom closing button. Which is triggered by onClick event. However, if I click on close button, the info window is closed, which is expected, but a new marker appears on the map, on a place where info window use to be. It looks like the onClick="infoWindow.close()" is the placeReclameMarker(event.latLng); simultaneously.

```
    var map;
    var infoWindow;
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.030698, 28.850098);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            placeReclameMarker(event.latLng);
        });

    }

    function placeReclameMarker(location) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            draggable: true,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function () {
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<input type="button" onclick="infoWindow.close()">'
            });
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks, like it was a google map bug/issue. The problem disappeared in a new version.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure you can visit infoWindow variable in infoWindow object inner.
try:

```
content: '<input type="button" onclick="parent.infoWindow.close()">'
```

or

```
content: '<input type="button" onclick="parent.parent.infoWindow.close()">'
```

or

```
content: '<input type="button" onclick="alert(infoWindow)">'
```

infoWindow variable must not to be undefined.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Found the solution. The thing is you should not only close the InfowWindow, but kill the marker also.

Try this;

```
var map;
var marker;
var infoWindow;
function whateverFunction() {
    // some code here to create the marker and the infoWindow
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    infoWindow.setContent('<input type=button name=Close onClick="marker.setMap(null);">');
}
```

Worked perfectly for me.